# Calculate Odds From A Given Probability

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

How does someone convert a given probability, to an Odds ratio? As an example:

$1$ in $4292 = 0.000232991612301957$ probability. That's easy enough to solve, because you just take $\frac{A}{B}$. My question is, though, how you take the probability $0.000232991612301957$ and convert it back to the odds of $1$ in $4292$? Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odds means "one in $x$," which is another way of writing "one per $x$," which is the same as "$1/x$", so you have

$$\frac{1}{4292}\approx 0.0002329 \implies \frac{1}{0.0002329}\approx 4292.$$

Comment: 1/Probability is the correct answer. Thank you for this; I can finally get back to programming now.

Comment: @Krythic No problem. If you liked the answer, you can accept it by clicking the tick under the up/down-vote buttons (note that you can only accept one answer per question). Cheers.

Comment: I will accept in 1 minute(required wait)

Comment: I've noticed an edge-case where this may fail. An example is 1/0.70 = 1.42 this seems to me like a problem where I am shifting towards the opposite end of the Odds spectrum. The answer is rounded to 1 which is technically correct, but the actual answer is 99(a) to 1(b). How can I handle this?

Comment: @Krythic I don't understand your question I'm afraid; odds are always given in integer values.

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up just deprecating this functionality in my engine and made a note of possible errors upon use of any probability > 0.01. I'm just going with precalculated probabilities now.